# Is there a better way of getting parent node of XPath query result?

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

Having markup like this:

```
<div class="foo">
   <div><span class="a1"></span><a href="...">...</a></div>
   <div><span class="a2"></span><a href="...">...</a></div>
   <div><span class="a1"></span>some text</div>
   <div><span class="a3"></span>some text</div>
</div>
```

I am interested in getting all `<a>` and `some text` **ONLY** if adjacent `span` is of class `a1`. So at the end of the whole code my result should be `<a>` from first `div` and `some text` from third one. It'd be easy if `<a>` and `some text` were inside `span` or `div` would have `class` attribute, but no luck.

What I am doing now is look for `span` with `a1` class:

```
//div[contains(@class,'foo')]/div/span[contains(@class,'a1')]
```

then I get its parent and do another `query()` with that parent as context node. This simply looks far from being efficient so the question clearly is if there is any better way to accomplish my goal?

---

**THE ANSWER ADDENDUM**

As per @MarcB [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875226/1235698), the right query to use is:

```
//div[contains(@class,'foo')]/div/span[contains(@class,'a1')]/..
```

but for `<a>` it may be better to use:

```
//div[contains(@class,'foo')]/div/span[contains(@class,'a1')]/../a
```

the get the `<a>` instead of its container.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The nice thing about xpath queries is that you can essentially treat them like a file system path, so simply having

```
//div[contains(@class,'foo')]/div/span[contains(@class,'a1')]/..
                                                              ^^
```

will find all your .a1 nodes that are below a .foo node, then move up one level to the a1 nodes' parents.

Comment: +1 for the reference to file system paths, that's how I've always thought of it but I've never heard it explained as such

Comment: I just checked manual prior asking the question but it seems I managed to miss ".." as it is clearly there. But FS reference made it clear instantly. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. when I first jumped into xpath, I flailed around like this for a while, but making the query<->path association was quite the eureka moment for me.

Comment: which is of course why that language is called X_Path_... But thinking of the query as a path is absolutely not helpful when you want to understand the finer details, especially if you want to update to XPath 2.0 someday. Then / is some kind of binary operator evaluating the right side for every node on the left side... (it has cost me weeks or months thinking of / as path separator, when I wrote a XPath parser)

Answer (score 16):

**An expression that is *better* than using reverse axis**:

```
//div[contains(@class,'foo')]/div[span[contains(@class,'a1')]]
```

This selects any `div` that is a child of a `div` whose `class` attribute contains the string "foo" and that (the selected `div`) has a `span` child whose `class` attribute contains the string "a1".

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "//div[contains(@class,'foo')]
          /div[span[contains(@class,'a1')]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<div class="foo">
   <div><span class="a1"></span><a href="...">...</a></div>
   <div><span class="a2"></span><a href="...">...</a></div>
   <div><span class="a1"></span>some text</div>
   <div><span class="a3"></span>some text</div>
</div>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected elements are copied to the output:**

```
<div>
   <span class="a1"/>
   <a href="...">...</a>
</div>
<div>
   <span class="a1"/>some text</div>
```

---

**II. Remarks on accessing an Html element by one of its classes**:

If it is known that the element can have only one class, then it isn't necessary at all to use `contains()`

**Don't use**:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'foo')]
```

**Use**:

```
//div[@class = 'foo']
```

**or, if there could be leading/trailing spaces, use:**

```
//div[normalize-space(@class) = 'foo']
```

**A crucial issue with**:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'foo')]
```

is that this selects any `div` with class such as "myfoo", "foo2" or "myfoo3".

**If the element may have more than one class, and to avoid the above issue, the correct XPath expression is**:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' foo ')]
```

Comment: don't forget that html allows multiple classes. `@class='foo'` will skip over `class="foo bar baz"`. as such, @contains is entirely valid, as long (as you point out), you watch for false positives

Comment: @MarcB, It seems that you haven't read or understood this answer -- It treats at length the case where an element has more than one class. Moreover, this answer provides a correct solution to that case -- not like the incorrect and simplistic `contains(@calss, someString)`