# Get Xpath parent node with DOMDocument PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I need to get the parent of a particular node in php.
I'm using DOMDocument and XPath.
My XML is this:

```
<ProdCategories>
<ProdCategory>

    <Id>138</Id>

    <Name>Parent Category</Name>

    <SubCategories>

        <ProdCategory>

            <Id>141</Id>

            <Name>Category child</Name>

        </ProdCategory>
   </SubCategories>
</ProdCategory>
</ProdCategories>
```

The php code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("ProdCategories_small.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//ProdCategory/Id[.="141"]/parent::*')->item(0);
print_r($nodes);
```

The print is:

> ```
>  DOMElement Object ( 
>  [tagName] => ProdCategory [schemaTypeInfo] => [nodeName] => ProdCategory [nodeValue] => 141 Category child [nodeType] => 1 [parentNode] => (object value omitted) [childNodes] => (object value omitted) [firstChild] => (object value omitted) [lastChild] => (object value omitted) [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
> ```

The **`[parentNode]`** is **`(object value omitted)`**, why? I would get

```
    <Id>138</Id>

    <Name>Parent Category</Name>`
```

Comment: Does the last node set in your question denote the desired output ? Your Xpath expression can be rewritten as `//ProdCategory[Id[.="141"]]`, does that work ?

Comment: @collapsar thank you for your response. No, doesn't work. The last node in my question it is what I want.

Comment: @collapsar - or even  `//ProdCategory[Id="141"]`

Comment: @DanielHaley no, not even this :(

Comment: I've checked the xpath expression using the xmlstarlet toolkit, it works as expected returning the inner `ProdCategory`. So the problem li likely related to the php implemantation.  However, first of all you must differentiate between the _match_ criterion and the _desired output_ and what you know about the structural relationship between them: so you want to match a `prodcategory` with id 141 and have `Id`/`Name` elements from the closest `ProdCategory` ancestor returned ?

Comment: @VolkerK what does it mean? but regardless of this , I would take the parent and somehow I see the output

Comment: @collapsar what's wrong in the implementation ? However I would like to simply take the id of the parent node `category child` , then the **Id 138**

Comment: The following xpath expression produces the result you indicated: `//ProdCategory[Id='141']/ancestor::ProdCategory/child::*[name() = 'Id' or name()='Name']`.

Comment: In the context of the matched `ProdCategory` of your xpath expression, the parent node is `SubCategories`. You have to use the `ancestor` axis to reach the outer `Prodcategory` - see my previous comment.

Comment: @collapsar i get an error **DOMXPath::query(): Invalid predicate**

Comment: if I run instead  this `//ProdCategory[Id='141']/ancestor::ProdCategory/`, it return all nodes, with child and not only `138`

Comment: I can't tell why php throws the xpath error. However, a workaround would be to use `//ProdCategory[Id='141']/ancestor::ProdCategory/child::*` and extract the first 2 items from the result set.

Answer (score 5):

> The **`[parentNode]`** is **`(object value omitted)`**, why?

This is because you use the [`print_r` function](http://php.net/manual/function.print-r) and it creates such an output ([via an internal helper function of the dom extension](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/dom/php_dom.c#494)). The line in code which is creating this is:

```
print_r($nodes);
```

The string "`(object value omitted)`" is given by the **DOMNode** when either `print_r` or `var_dump` are used on it. It tells you, that the object *value* of that field (named *parentNode*) is not displayed but omitted.

From that message you could conclude that the field has a value that is an object. A simple check for the class-name could verify this:

```
echo get_class($nodes->parentNode), "\n"; # outputs  "DOMElement"
```

Compare that with fields which are an integer or an (empty) string:

```
[nodeType] => 1
...
[prefix] => 
[localName] => ProdCategory
```

So I hope this clears it up for you. Just access the field to get the parent node object:

```
$parent = $nodes->parentNode;
```

and done.

If you wonder about a certain string that PHP gives you and you have the feeling it might be something internal, you can quickly search all of PHP's codebase on http://lxr.php.net/, [here is an example query for the string in your question](http://lxr.php.net/search?q=%22%28object+value+omitted%29%22&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=PHP_5_4).

Answer (score 3):

Just treat the xpath query nodes as filesystem paths, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875226/5043552)

Move up 2 nodes and get the parent and get what you need from it, such as the Id or Name.

Example:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("ProdCategories_small.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$parentNode = $xpath->query('//ProdCategory[Id="141"]/../..')->item(0);

$id = $xpath->query('./Id', $parentNode)->item(0);
$name = $xpath->query('./Name',$parentNode)->item(0);

print "Id: " . $id->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
print "Name: " . $name->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
```